# Query on large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query -

```
SELECT  n.fname
       ,ii.render AS practitioner_npi
       ,n.address AS address1
       ,substring(n.postal,0,6) AS zip
       ,substring(n.postal,6,4) AS zip4
       ,ii.count AS count
  FROM
  (
        SELECT render, count(*) AS count
        FROM dx sl
        JOIN annual caq
        ON DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date_of_service::date) >= caq.start
        JOIN entities n
        ON sl.render = n.npi
        WHERE dx_cd IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT dx_cd
          FROM dx_per_code pc
          JOIN bucket bac
          ON pc.code = bac.hcpccode
          WHERE
          bucketname = 'something'
          AND dx_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 5
        )
        AND n.npi_type = '1'
        GROUP BY render
  )
   ii
  JOIN npi n ON n.npi = ii.render
  LEFT JOIN taxonomy t ON t.code = n.taxonomy
ORDER BY ii.count DESC;
```

The dx table does not have any indexes and contains approax 8B records. This query currently takes 20 minutes to run. What indexes/optimizations can I make to get this to run faster?

Comment: Explain what the query is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results can help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My postgres version is PostgreSQL 10.14 and the dx table has no indexes.